# How to enable both swipe to delete and a delete button made in edit mode in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

By default edit mode is on, that's why swipe on cell, it will delete like this,
   [image]
and when click on edit following method use to delete the data
[image]

Right now it works correctly but either one of them is going to use. I want to use both method for delete cell.

Please help me to find some code snippet or tutorial link

Comment: What do you mean "I want to use both method for delete cell."?

Comment: means, by default swipe to delete is enable.. but when edit button is clicked delete with rearrange going to appear

Answer (score 1):

The natural iOS behaviour for Edit mode in a UITableView is just showing the '-' button for deletion, thats the way I recommend you to use, because of the users are use to deleting on that way.

With this library, you can assign custom buttons and actions for both Swipe directions. Maybe with it you can achieve what you want.

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

I would try to add a custom right UIBarButton with a custom action, and after it get pressed, you can try to force swiping the cell to both directions, and showing the buttons you want.

Comment: i implemented both swipe and delete button with rearrange...but it works only one at a time, both are not working together